# App crash when navigating to user page

Tags: bug, android-app, user-information

When I attempt to load a question after disabling my Internet connection, I receive an alert that says that it couldn't load the question. So far, so good.

When I try and load my user profile page with no Internet connection, the application crashes.

This was noticed when initially clicking on the user profile, as well as clicking on a site-specific summary within the user profile (that is, I clicked on my user profile with an active Internet connection, loaded the page, disabled my Internet connection, and clicked on "Stack Overflow")

---

**Version:**

- Stack Exchange: *1.0.7*
- Android: *4.3*
- Phone: *HTC One*

Comment: Confirmed with Nexus 4, Android 4.4.2 on v1.0.6: 1) Start the app without internet connection and open user page. 2) Start the app with internet connection, wait until the feed is fully loaded then turn off the internet and open user page. 3) Open user page with internet connection, turn off the internet and click a site-specific summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed as of 1.0.33. It now explicitly says that the profile page cannot be loaded, and to try again when Internet access has been restored.

Thank you, Android app development team!